# refactor d3 from tsv to json and replace type function

Tags: d3.js

I need to factor out the type function so I can use a json variable instead of tsv; I am already doing a data.forEach() to parse the date so that's OK.   I haven't been able to figure out what this does:

```
for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = d[columns[i]] 
/ 100;
```

in

```
function type(d, i, columns) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = d[columns[i]] 
/ 100;
return d;
}
```

this is the example:
[Stacked bar](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function just normalizes values.

you can see that each row's sum is 100. So, this function divides each one to 100 and result will be between 0 and 1.

This function plays middleware role, it will be applied, before you start using loaded tsv data.

So, if you want to use json, you can skip this function and make values in json 100 times smaller. Or you can keep this func and just change from

`d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {`

to

`d3.json("your-json-file-url.json", type, function(error, data) {`

Comment: I totally missed this; sounds so much simpler when you explain it and also explains why my chart was not displaying thanks! I am getting an unexpected token when i do this:  d.[Google Chrome] = d.[Google Chrome]/100;  What am i missing?